# Apple certificate from windows loading

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, push-notification, certificate

I am trying to get a iOS certificate from windows. I was following this [steps](http://www.phonegap.es/2015/03/como-crear-certificado-ios-para-phonegap-build-desde-windows/) (it is spanish... but easy to follow: almost all are openssl commands) yesterday and I could get a certificate. The problem is that I want to obtain a push notification certificate, and for this what I do is (on developers apple web):

iOS Apps-> App IDs-> click on my AppID-> click on edit-> enable pushnotification (really, I clicked it enabled when I create the AppId by first time) and generate a certificate. On the next screen I choose the same .certSigningRequest wich one I made the developer certificate and , but loading spins and spins to infinity.

Further, I can do almost nothing... when I try to revoke a certificate, it ask me this

> Revoke Certificate
>   Revoking this certificate will invalidate it and any related services or provisioning profiles that use this certificate may be affected.

But finaly doesn´t remove it. When I try to delete an app id, I see a modal that I think ask about the same, but it goes fast and the page change showing only:

> HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

The Provisioning Profiles is the same than the certificate... it ask me if I am sure... but finally doesn´t remove.

Now if I want to revoke the pushnotification to he appid it ask me if I am sure, but after this confirmation, the loading spin and spin and never finish. If I want to create a new development certificate, when it ask me for the certSigningRequest I upload (a new one, created following the same steps than the first), but the loading spins and spins and never ends.

why I can do nothing!!!???? Am I doing something wrong??

PS: To generate the pushnotification certificate I was following [this oficial guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringPushNotifications/ConfiguringPushNotifications.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it seems that using other browser had solved it.
Who would have thought it?
Thank you.